# Are there any cons to heating orange and grape juice?

Tags: reheating, juice, oranges, grapes

Very simply I'd like to offer guests mixed heated orange and grape juice in the winter. I'm not sure why this isn't more common since hot lemonade and hot cider exist.

Are there any nutritional cons to heating grape or orange juice?

Comment: Hello Slamice and welcome! Questions on healt-properties of food are off-topic here: The question might be put on hold for this. Could you please re-write it? You should check in the help center (top right of every page), which questions are on-topic and which questions should be avoided. Thanks!

Comment: I would add some grappa or other alcohol, and I promise your guests will love it :)

Answer (score 2):

That's actually pretty a pretty common thing. Add a few cloves and a cinnamon stick and you'll have [Mulled Orange Juice](http://www.croque-maman.com/mulled-orange-juice/), or the same with [grape juice](https://www.welchs.com/recipes/drinks-and-smoothies/warm-mulled-grape-juice). That recipe adds orange zest, lemon juice, cloves, nutmeg and a cinnamon stick. [This one](http://www.tasteofhome.com/recipes/mulled-grape-cider) starts with grapes.

I can't speak to the nutritional effects of heating the juices, but mulled juices sound nice on a cold, winter day. There certainly isn't anything toxic to be nervous about.